# Get Column Names from SQLDatasource

Tags: asp.net

So I'm using a SQL data source that fires a Store procedure using the selected value of a drop down list as a parameter to return one of a multitude of differing tables. Then I have a gridview that uses this SQLdatasource as it's datasource to display the returned values.

What I want is to be able to get at the column names at run time so that I can use it in a later method. However the SQLDatasource doesn't seem to have a property to get at this data and when I try to get at the columns of the Datagridview after I databind it the gridview only shows a single column (the auto-generated select column). Is there a way to get at this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using the SQLDatasource, but you can do this easily in the codebehind if you load your data into a DataTable.  E.g.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var connectionString = "your connection string";
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("stored_procedure_name", db);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    db.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(reader);
}
var columns = dt.Columns;
```

Each column has a ColumnName property.  You can use Linq to get the column names as an array:

```
var columnNameArray = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Every column does have a ColumnName property...but not all columns necessarily have names: `select EmployeeID , HourlyWage * HoursWorked from ...` is perfectly legal SQL and the second column of the result set has no name.

Comment: True enough.  In the context of the question, though, it sounds like he will always have column names.  I consider it a best practice to always have column names for my resultsets anyway.